# How to parse a tabular file and save it in a suitable dataformat as we iterate?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and there is not enough help onlie for starters like me. 
Say if I have a tabular file named "foo". This file contains info seperated by tabs, For example:

```
Country       Continent          Region

USA           North_America      West
UAE           Asia               Middle_East
China         Asia               East
France        Europe             West
Chile         South_America      West
```

How can I parse "Country" and "Region" for only USA, China ans Chile and save it in a taabular format including headers??

I know it sounds basic, but i'm very new to coding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find online tutorials to help you with this. Check this page: 
[Web resources for R](https://sites.google.com/a/tamu.edu/dlcarlson/home/r-project-for-statistical-computing/r-resources-on-the-web)

Your first step will be to bring your tab delimited file into R as a data frame (`read.delim()`). Then you need to learn how to extract rows from your data frame according the the criteria you list to create another data frame. If you want to export that new data frame you will use `write.table(. . . , sep="\t")`. If this is confusing read a short tutorial about R (< 100 pages) to get started. When you get stuck, ask questions here showing us what you tried first.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do the required thing, I will mostly focus on the two popular methods in using R.

### Creating dataframe that you have in R

```
# To create a tabular dataframe that contains data
foo <-
  data.frame(
    Country = c("USA", "UAE", "China", "France", "Chile"),
    Continent = c("North_America", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "South_America"),
    Region = c("West", "Middle_East", "East", "West", "West"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

#### Method 1: Doing required using Base R (no required package installation)

```
# foo$Country --> selects specified column
# foo$Country %in% c("USA", "China", "Chile") --> Set the condition to choose only those rows
# ,] --> means get all columns
# foo[foo$Country %in% c("USA", "China", "Chile"),] --> means for the set condition select data from original
# new_foo <- --> this is an assignment operator to add the result to a new dataframe
new_foo <- foo[foo$Country %in% c("USA", "China", "Chile"),]
```

#### Method 2: Doing required using Dplyr

```
# install.packages("dplyr") --> you should install it if you do not have it (make sure you are connected to the internet)
library(dplyr)

# Will create a new tabular dataframe called new_foo (you can change its name)
new_foo <-
  # We get the created dataframe
  foo %>%
  # We filter to get only the required countries
  filter(Country %in% c("USA", "China", "Chile")) %>%
  # To parse only Country and Region column
  select(Country, Region)
```